How to deal with LigHTTPD subdomain-to-port reverse proxy not found?
I'm using LigHTTPD 1.4.69 (SSL) for a website and want to use it for easy access to file browser from a subdomain such as file.example.com instead of including the port 8080 in the address.
I enabled mod_proxy and appended this to 10-proxy.conf:
$HTTP["host"] == "file.example.com" {
    proxy.balance = "hash"
    proxy.debug = 1
    proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                               "port" => 8080 ) )
}

Additionally, file browser's address is set to 127.0.0.1. I tried it while it was set on the public IP before this and it worked perfectly with IP:port.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I used the wiki to write my config, I'm not sure where it could've gone wrong

@Giacomo1968 Done, thank you. It's not the case in the actual config, I copied it poorly, apologies

@Meragone Ensure the port 8080 is listening locally and confirm it loads locally. Ensure to restart/reload the lighttpd service with systemctl since you made the changes. Check all applicable log files and see if anything in there gives any clue: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/lighttpd-log-files.32337/, https://serverfault.com/questions/259384/where-is-error-log-in-lighttpd, and https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/lighttpd-log-files.32337/

If you are from outside firewall remapping port 8080 from the outside world coming in to another locally listening port [some NAT config] that is not 8080 on the listening server, that could be the difference there so double check the basics and ensure there has not been oversight at these levels.

Wild guess, but can you bind the service to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 and restart the service?
I don’t know why it might work, but binding on an address of 0.0.0.0 basically tells the system to run the service on any/every address on the machine. Running it purely on 127.0.0.1 tells the service to bind only to 127.0.0.1 (local loopback) via IPv4.
